# PHP: Allow letters, numbers and arabic character

Tags: php, arabic

How can i allow arabic character in preg_match ?

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", "لحمدلله")) {
    echo "Firstname can only use letters, numbers and arabic characters.";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z0-9]+$/u", "لحمدلله")) {
    echo "Firstname can only use letters, numbers and arabic characters.";
}
```

Comment: why you use "u" at the end ?